# Atmel SAM3X / SAM3A, handle interrupts from Parallel Input/Output Controller (Peripherals)

Tags: arm, interrupts, microprocessor, atmel, peripheral

I want to enable the PA8 pin in a processor (Atmel SAM3X / SAM3A).

I have set:

```
PIOA_MDER[7]=0
PIOA_MDDR[7]=0
PIO_OER[7]=0
PIO_ODR[7]=1
```

so that the tri-state buffer will no longer send data out of the pin, and the pin is enabled to receive data from the environment and to send interrupts if needed.

I also want to set my interrupt to rising edge, so I also set:

```
PIOA_RHLSR[7]=1
PIOA_FELLSR[7]=0
PIO_ESR[7]=1
PIOA_LSR[7]=0
```

My problem now is how to modify NVIC registers so that this interrupt is enabled. I mean, on a rising edge on this pin, the state of this pin is pending, and then the changes I will apply to NVIC causes this pending state to active state.

My interrupt group priority and subgroup priority are both 3. I know how to modify Interrupt set-enable register, interrupt clear-enable register, application interrupt and reset control register, and interrupt priority register.

Still, my problem is that now I don't have any number for interrupts from this specific pin (PIOA8), so it is different from the time I had my interrupt number (from 1 to 240)

Does someone know which register in the NVIC I should modify? Thanks for your help.

## update

I think I'd better say that I need to work with peripherals, now, how to inform NVIC about interrupts?

Comment: Can you please re-format your question to make it easier to read and highligh the actual question?

Comment: Hi. What point do you think I should explain? 
Very brief, I want to enable one of PIO pins, namely, pin A[7] so that it can receive interrupts from the environment. My problem is that I don't know what changes I need to apply to NVIC registers? suppose this interrupt, has both priority=3 and subpriority=3. Normally, I could solve this problem for a specific interrupt with a specific interrupt number (from 1 to 240), But here, I don't know my interrupt number, so I don't know what registers in the NVIC and how, should I change to configure my microprocessor. If you had further questions, ask.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more readable and make the question explicit.

Comment: Thanks for that. I hope I'm able to find an answer!
If you have further questions, please don't hesitate to ask.